# Python 3: TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'float' and 'str'

Tags: python, python-3.x

Can somebody tell me why i get the error code: TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'float' and 'str'

```
    while True:
        c = input("Gib die Temperatur in Grad Celcius ein:  ")
        try:
            c = float(c)
            return c
        except ValueError:
            print("Das ist keine gültige Angabe für eine Temperatur")


def convert_to_temperature(c):
    k = c + 273.15
    return k


if __name__ == "__main__":
    c = get_temperature()
    print("Das sind " + str(convert_to_temperature(c) + " Kelvin."))
```

Comment: I don't see a `get_temperature()` function.

Comment: `print("Das sind " + str(convert_to_temperature(c)) + " Kelvin.")` or simpler, `print("Das sind", convert_to_temperature(c), "Kelvin.")`

Comment: check you bracket placement, last line should be `print("Das sind " + str(convert_to_temperature(c))+ " Kelvin.")` - or as an f-string `print(f"Das sind {convert_to_temperature(c)} Kelvin.")`

Comment: Unrelated to the error, but I would suggest a better name for `convert_to_temperature`. Since the parameter is already a temperature in Celsius you might want to call this function `convert_celsius_to_fahrenheit`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are misplacing the parentheses when you attempt to transform the result of `convert_to_temperature(c)` which returns a float to a string. This is your line which is incorrect, because `str()` is being applied to `convert_to_temperature(c) + " Kelvin."` which if you check the individual types:

```
print(type(convert_to_temperature(c)))
print(type(" Kelvin."))
```

Returns:

```
float
str
```

Therefore the `str()` must be applied only to the output of `convert_to_temperature(c)`:

```
print("Das sind " + str(convert_to_temperature(c)) + " Kelvin.")
```

Allowing for a concatenation of strings via the `+` operator.

Answer (score 0):

```
I think you missed the get_temperature() function header (supplied here). And the last line you can modify to make it work: 

def get_temperature():
        while True:
            c = input("Gib die Temperatur in Grad Celcius ein:  ")
            try:
                c = float(c)
                return c
        
            except ValueError:
                print("Das ist keine gültige Angabe für eine Temperatur")
    
    
    
    
    if __name__ == "__main__":
        c = get_temperature()
        print(f"Das sind {convert_to_temperature(c)} Kelvin.")
```